# Python dictionary SyntaxError

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax-error

I'm moving to Python from PHP and I seem to be stuck in my first hour of learning Python.

This seems to be such a basic question that I'm having trouble finding an answer - so please forgive me.

When I try to create a dictionary I enter:

```
numbers = ('Bob':'322', 'Mary':'110', 'Joe':'839')
```

I get the error:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    numbers = ('Bob':'322', 'Mary':'110', 'Joe':'839')
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've tried this in both the command line and in IDLE and the same error appears. What am I doing wrong? I really can't see it. Again sorry for low level of this question.

Comment: Tuples use (), dictionaries use {}, lists use []

Comment: You should also note that if you want the values to be numbers instead of strings, omit the quotes around them. `'322'` is a string (single or double quotes, it doesn't matter in Python), while `322` is a number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dictionaries use curly braces `{}`, not parentheses `()`

`numbers = {'Bob':'322', 'Mary':'110', 'Joe':'839'}`

Comment: Are you kidding me? Jeez thanks. Now it looks like I have to write a bad review of a course I just purchased.

Comment: No problem man. Good luck on your transition from PHP to Python!